# Unable to access api hosted in EKS and routed via istio-ingressgateway with NLB

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, istio-gateway, aws-nlb

New to AWS here, Trying to expose API and having issues.

I have an API deployed to AWS's EKS cluster, where my API is connected to a clusterIP service.
That clusterIP service is attached to a `Virtual Service`(VS) exposing API's port and a fixed Hostname with routes as a prefix, this `VS` is connected to a `Gateway` (ingressgateway) describing both `HTTP`(80) and `HTTPS`(443) for all (* asterisk as hosts) connections.
Post that all our HTTP and HTTPS requests are mapped to 2 node ports under `istio-ingressgateway` hosted under the `istio-system` namespace.
Now, these 2 exposed `nodePorts` are consumed by the target groups registered over the same nodePorts, and these target groups are listened to by our `NLB`.
The NLB is connected to a DNS entry in `Route53` by its NLB's `DNS Name` of `CNAME`(also tried with `A`) type.
Now, I am trying to access my API from the browser using the above setup, but whenever I try to (with A-type) I get `500: internal server error` but no errors on my API's pods. And `CNAME` no results, it just gives timeout.

I followed the same process as how another API is deployed on the same cluster, but the other API is working fine, whereas my API is not accessible.

**Edit 1**: try capturing the error with `CloudWatch`, but we got the not-so-informative error:

```
{
"requestId": "e0etYh9BvHcES6A=",
"IP": "<ip-address>",
"requestTime": "16/Jan/2023:05:19:17 +0000",
"httpMethod": "GET",
"routeKey": "$default",
"status": "500",
"protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
"responseLength": "35"
}
```

**Edit 2:** was able to make it work.
Solution: as our NLB is configured with an `internal` scheme, we needed to connect it with the API gateway other than that the `route53` record needed to be configured with an `A` scheme and once the changes were in place, we are able to access our API from browser.

Questions:

1. Is this the proper way to expose an API from the EKS cluster with an NLB and istio-ingressgateway service?
2. Are we only allowed to have one service routed via istio-ingressgateway under `istio-system`?  Do we need to write a new one for another API?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is related to the NLB being configured with an internal scheme and not being connected to the API Gateway. The Route 53 record need to be configured with an A scheme instead of CNAME.

Comment: Yes, i have updated the question with what worked for us.